# WPF Button Styling, Templates?

Tags: wpf, templates, button, styles

I am very close to getting what I want, but I don't like the background poking out beyond the border on the corners. Can anyone point me to the right way to style the background to also round the corners? thanks.

```
<Button  FontSize="16" Height="50" >
    <Button.Content>
        <Border CornerRadius="5" Padding="5" Margin="0" BorderBrush="GreenYellow" BorderThickness="2" Height="50" >
            <TextBlock Text="Work Order Manager" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Border>

    </Button.Content>

    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkGoldenrod"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>

</Button>
```

Comment: what u want background corner round or button corner round???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to round the whole button then move CornerRadius to button's template:

```
<Button  FontSize="16" Height="50" Padding="5" Content="Work Order Manager" >
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="GreenYellow"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                CornerRadius="5" 
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                                >
                            <ContentPresenter 
                                Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                                VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                />
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkGoldenrod"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```